# Creating stored procedure in MS SQL through pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am trying to create a store procedure in master in mssql through python code. The following is my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=localhost; database=master; trusted_connection=true",
                      autocommit=True) 
cursor = conn.cursor()
sqlcommand = """
                USE master
                GO
                CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myCustomSystemProc
                AS
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'myCustomCode'
                END
                GO
                EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'sp_myCustomSystemProc'
             """     
cursor.execute(sqlcommand)

cursor.commit()

conn.commit()
```

After running this python code, I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "auto_complete.py", line 27, in <module>
>   cursor.execute(sqlcommand)  
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); 
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. (111); 
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. (102); 
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> Incorrect syntax near 'sp_myCustomSystemProc'. (102)")
> ```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your connection string already specifies the `master` database (i.e. `database=master;`), simply remove

```
USE master
GO
```

from your query.